# Shopify Application Url keeps changing

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am having an issue where I try and run "npm run dev" and it tells me the callback urls need to be changed to the values presented, then run "npm run shopify app config push" which I do.

When I run the command, however, I get the error "Command no longer supported" and instead tells me to run "npm run shopify app deploy", which I do.

After running the deploy command, I try running "npm run dev" again, but when I do, it tells me the callback urls need to be changed again, and the loop keeps going.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Why does the application url change every time I run "npm run dev"?

I've also tried running dev, then in a separate cli tab, change the callback urls and run the deploy command. I have also changed the urls in the partners page while dev was still running, but none of that works. Every time I run dev and click on the 'Preview Url", the app page errors out saying it can't find the page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to update your config file to prevent this from happening.

In your `shopify.app.toml` simply change the following.

```ini
[build]
automatically_update_urls_on_dev = false
```

[image]

You can find the reference to that in the doc https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/configuration

Comment: It was already set to false.

Comment: can you show your config file, without sensitive info?